# My HTML and CSS files won't link pleas

Tags: css

i cant link my http file with my css file . please help here is my sample of code for http

```
<doctype!html>
<html lang =eng>
 <head>
 <title> hello world </title>
 <link rel="stylesheet"  href="style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
 <p id="tuna">my name</P>
  <p>weff</p>
  <p>stormy</p>
  </body>
  </html>
```

now css file

```
   #tuna{color:green;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is correct. Maybe it's just because the file style.css is not found in the directory where the html file is. Please put style.css in the same folder where html file is.

Answer (score 0):

make sure, that html and css files are in one document together.

Answer (score 0):

your code worked just fine for me. However, you want to make sure that the CSS and HTML file are in the same directory OR make sure that the correct file path is used.

Answer (score 0):

First of all correct the `doctype` tag.

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Now write `link` tag for `css` properly.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">`

---

Now locate the `.css` file and put it in the same directory where your `html` document is.

If it is in another directory so use **relative** path. Like write like this if it is one directory back.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css" type="text/css">`

Or if you want to locate it from the root directory so write **absolute** path like this.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/directory1/directory2/style.css">`type="text/css">`